# Alternative to Oculus Rift

Tags: vr-headset

I was hoping for the Oculus Rift to be released for a price of less than 500 € (~550 USD). Since it it now announced for 700 € (~760 USD), I wonder whether there's an alternative announced to be ready this year (in 2016).

Perhaps I was too fixated on the Oculus Rift, but I have not listened much to the VR market and competitors of Facebook.

Requirements:

- max. 500 € price
- released or announced for 2016
- resolution of approx. 1080×1200 per eye, like the Rift
- works on Windows, Linux is not required
- comes with an SDK, games not required

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: well, that link does not fulfill the requirements regarding price, release date, resolution and SDK and thus is not an answer to the question according the rules of this site. Perhaps yes, I'll do that research and if I find the answer, I'll add it below.

Comment: Are you completely sure the Oculus is not what you want? The price you read (wherever you read it) is wrong: https://shop.oculus.com/en-us/cart/ It's sold for USD600 (~550€)

Comment: Yeah, the pricing... that's the funny part: USD 600 in the US, but 700 € in Germany.

Answer (score 6):

[OSVR](http://www.osvr.org/) is currently in the development kit stage. It's designed to be a low cost, easy to customize alternative

Price: ~300USD (350 € for Germany)

Screen: The devkit uses a 1920x1080 single full HD screen - this might be upgradable in future

Seems to be available now. Has an [SDK](http://osvr.github.io/build-with/), works on Windows.

Its also open source hardware and software so you could customise it as needed.

Says in facebook that [they ship to europe](https://www.facebook.com/OpenSourceVR/posts/1766283393600174?comment_id=1766503816911465&reply_comment_id=1766551573573356&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D)